# R crosstalk package - modify filter_select height

Tags: r, crosstalk

Is there a way to reduce the height of filter_select?

Following css works for reducing the width but height doesn't seem to do anything for the height

I want to make the height shorter

```
<style>
.crosstalk-input-select {
  color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;  
}
</style>
```

```
library(crosstalk)
shared_mtcars <- SharedData$new(mtcars)
filter_select("auto", "Automatic", shared_mtcars, ~ifelse(am == 0, "Yes", "No"))
```